# Replace a label with textfield in javafx at same position

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have a number of Labels in my VBox and on click of a button i want to replace all these labels with textfields.

Comment: Please provide more information. Are there any special conditions on the labels, like layout, style, text,.. A [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: No there is no special condition on the labels. They are just displaying some text that I am reading from database. On click of a button(or check box) these label will change in editable textfields. I want my textfields to be  replaced at same label position. say label1 will be replaced by textfielld1 at position of label1.

Comment: I have tried layering, so that my front layer will be of labels and background layer would be of textfields. On click of the button i can move my background layer to front. But while loading that fxml error comes: 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer. 
I searched this issue and it says to add mobile library and it is licensed so i cannot use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your `VBox` and replace the:

```
VBox vBox = ...
int currentPos = 0;
Map<Integer, TextField> toInsert = new HashMap<>(); // map with TextFields that need to be inserted at position
for (Iterator<Node> iterator = vBox.getChildren().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Node child = iterator.next();
    if (child instanceof Label) {
        Label lbl = (Label)child;
        TextField text = new TextField(lbl.getText());
        iterator.remove(); // remove the label that is at index currentPos
        toInsert.put(currentPos, text);

    }
    currentPos++;
}
for (Integer pos : toInsert.keySet()) {
    TextField field = toInsert.get(pos);
    vBox.getChildren().add(pos, field); // Add the Text field at the old position of the Label
}
```

In the first loop you remove the labels and create the replacement `TextField`s and remember at which position you need to insert them later on. This cannot happen in the same loop. Then in the second loop you add those `TextField`s to the `VBox` at the position you assigned them.

**Edit:**
Based on @fabian's valid comments the above proposed solution may cause problems. Here is an alternative approach, that creates a second `VBox` where all non `Label` nodes are copied over and the `Label`s are replaced with `TextField`. I assume that the original `VBox` is a child element of some `Parent`.

```
Parent parent = ... // Parent of VBox
VBox vbox = ...
// Find the index of vBox in Parent
int position = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<parent.getChildren().size(); i++) {
    if (parent.getChildren().equals(vBox)) {
        position = i;
        break; // found our position, no need to look further
    }
}
VBox copyVBox = new VBox();
for (Node child : vBox.getChildren()) {
    if (child instanceof Label) {
        Label lbl = (Label)child;
        TextField text = new TextField(lbl.getText());
        copyVBox.getChildren().add(text);        
    } else {
        copyVBox.getChildren().add(child);
    }
}
parent.getChildren().remove(vBox);
parent.getChildren().add(position, copyVBox);
```

Comment: You need to modify this code since the order in the key set is unpredictable and inserting in any order but ascending order will lead to wrong results. You could e.g. replace the children using `set` in the second loop and not removing the elements in the first loop, use `.stream().sorted().forEach(...)` instead of the second loop or use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: BTW: You **can** modify a list while iterating over it, but you'll need to use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) for this...

Comment: @AnuragSharma layering? In my answer I posted an approach that allows you to put the `Label` and `TextField` in the same position; also using `StackPane`s containing both `Label` and corresponding `TextField` could be an option, if this is what you meant...

Comment: No, I mean that I can have a VBox and have two layers(of pane layout) for it. One layer will contain labels and other will have textfields.

Comment: @AnuragSharma With a single `VBox` this is not possible (or only with pretty complicated workarounds which can more easily be done using a different layout). A `VBox` will calculate the position of all it's managed children based on the size of preceeding managed children and will not position unmanaged children at all, which means every child is either influences the layout or it will be placed in the wrong position. You could of course put 2 `VBox`es (one for `Label`s, one for `TextField`s) in a `Pane` and make only one visible, but the corresponding children will not be aligned this way.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend using a `VBox`, since replacing the children will likely modify the layout causing a effect that could confuse the user.
Instead I recommend using a `GridPane`, which allows you to place multiple children in a single cell. This way you could put all the `Label`s and `VBox`es in the grid, but set the `visible` property of the `TextField`s to `false`. This means both `Label` and `TextField` will be used for layout calculation and you can simply swap between "editing mode" and "normal mode" by inverting the `visible` property of all children:

**FXML**

```xml
<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxml.LabelReplaceController">
    <children>
        <GridPane fx:id="grid">
            <children>
                <TextField fx:id="t1" text="Hello World!" visible="false" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
                <Label text="${t1.text}" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                <TextField fx:id="t2" text="foo" visible="false" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
                <Label text="${t2.text}" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <TextField fx:id="t3" text="bar" visible="false" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
                <Label text="${t3.text}" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            </children>
        </GridPane>
        <ToggleButton selected="false" onAction="#selectionChanged" text="edit"/>
    </children>
</HBox>
```

```
public class LabelReplaceController {

    @FXML
    private Pane grid;

    @FXML
    private void selectionChanged(ActionEvent event) {
        for (Node child : grid.getChildren()) {
            child.setVisible(!child.isVisible());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But keeping in my further functionalities to be less complex gridpane is a better option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the much needed help